# Is it possible for me to write to Outlook using Excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Here is my dream; I have a master sheet in excel that contains 100 names and dates. I want to write a VBA code that will take those dates and times and throw them into a shared outlook calendar. Part 2 of the code would be to compare if the date was changed , if so delete previous event and make a new one. I also need it to be able to change the color of the event. If anyone can point me in a direction to start that would be awesome, thank you! Also I will have to look to see if excel macro recorder can record outlook events...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel Macro recorder will not record anything outside of the current Excel instance. You can **automate** Outlook using VBA but you need to write the code yourself (or find some).

In the Excel VBA Editor, the first step is to choose the Tools menu, References and tick the **Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library** (or 12.0 for Office 2007).

After ticking the reference, typical Outlook automation code might start like this:

```
Sub AutomateOutlook()
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
End Sub
```

[Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms268893.aspx) Overview: MSDN

There are more restrictions with Outlook than other applications. You might want to research firstly whether you can write to a shared calendar. This [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6749ee0f-62a2-4315-b46f-d663ab7dbfed/add-appt-to-a-shared-calendar-using-vba) link is also relevant.